# websockets with mobile clients

Tags: mobile, websocket

Is is must to have the client to be browser for a web server? Is this a good architecture for mobile clients to have some non browser client and get data from webservers?

I am thinking of implementing a basic browser at mobile client. Login using web methos and rest of the communication (monitoring info at every 10sec)  be done using web sockets. Will this work?

Can I implement web sockets without JS?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can implement WebSockets outside the browser, and without any JavaScript involved. You could have i.e. a Android native Java application that talks to a server over WebSockets.

WebSockets is a protocol. The WebSockets API defined for JavaScript running in the browser is something different.

You can authenticate a WebSockets connection during the WebSockets handshake using any method available with HTTP (i.e. basic auth, digest, cram-md5, client cert.-based (TLS), and so on), since the WebSockets handshake is still like any other HTTP conversation. It is only *after* the handshake is completed that WS is different from HTTP.

Note, that what you likely want on the server side is not a plain old Web server, but a WebSockets server/framework.

Whether using WS to connect mobile clients is "a good architecture" is a bit vague. I would say: *if* you decide to have your mobile client talk to a server, and that server is under your control, and you want to leverage WS advantages like near real-time/bidirectional, then it might be good. Better than cooking your own low-level protocol.

Comment: +1 WebSockets are most definitely becoming the standard for bi-directional server to client communication and the client definitely doesn't have to be a web browser/JavaScript.

Comment: Web sockets are not very reliable in the mobile world as of today. A lot of cellular carriers are blocking websocket connections entirely. So don't rely on them too much

Comment: @user1169629: yes - if you don't use TLS. When using secure WebSocket ("wss"), which runs over TLS, mobile operators cannot proxy or block (since they can't look inside the traffic) and it'll just work.